# Weka multi-perceptron with multiple hidden layers

Tags: neural-network, weka

I'm trying to use Multi-Perceptron in Weka Knowledge Flow. In the attachment you can see the setting for the block.
As written in the help:
"hiddenLayers -- This defines the hidden layers of the neural network. This is a list of positive whole numbers. 1 for each hidden layer. Comma seperated. To have no hidden layers put a single 0 here. This will only be used if autobuild is set. There are also wildcard values 'a' = (attribs + classes) / 2, 'i' = attribs, 'o' = classes , 't' = attribs + classes."

However, it's still a little bit confusing for me. How can I build a neural network with 3 hidden layers, each has different number of units (say 2,5,6). And can you help explain wildcard values? I think it's only for number of hidden layers, not for number of hidden units in each layer.

Thank you.[image]

Comment: I messed around with the MultilayerPerceptron in the explorer, and found that you can provide comma separated numbers for the number of **units** for each layer. This means that '2,5,6' makes 3 hidden layers, left to right, with 2, 5, and 6 nodes per layer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The GUI option will help you work through this. If you supply '2,5,6' to the hidden layers, it will create 3 layers with 2, 5, and 6 units 
respectively. The wildcard values seem to be shortcuts for the numbers they represent (a = (# of attributes + # of classes) / 2 , etc). Here are a couple visual steps representing what I mean.

---

You can see the 'a, 2, 5, 6' in `hiddenLayers`.
[image]

a = # of attributes  + # of classes / 2

There are 6 attributes and 1 class, so a = 7 / 2 = 3

This means that we expect to see 3 units in the first hidden layer, then 2, 5, and 6, followed by the 1 unit in the output layer.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the clear example. 
Two follow up questions:
1) how did you find the meaning of the wildcard 'a'? where is it specified?
2) how did you get the NN architecture visualization?

Comment: @Amitai this should help: http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/functions/MultilayerPerceptron.html

Comment: As for the visualisation, if you click the white bar after selecting the classifier, you get the options. Just set GUI to true :)